# How to access Google Doc Api with service account?

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I want my web server to request google doc via service account. The reason I choose the service account is I don't want any login information from my user.

Tried below code but this throws `The caller does not have permission` errors.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'xxx.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
    )
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    response = service.documents().get(documentId='xxx').execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on creating a service account and reading a Google doc https://www.futurice.com/blog/read-goog-doc-using-service-account

The document needs to either be shared with the service account's email address OR be publicly shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to impersonate the user, you have to share the document with the service account from drive in order to give it permission's to read/write

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to make sure the Service Account has access rights to the files it is attempting to read/write.*

#### More Information:

The `The caller does not have permission` error message indicates that the file with ID `documentID` has sharing permissions such that the service account you are using does not have the permission to do what you are asking it to do - be that reading or writing.

If impersonation of the user really is infeasible for you, the file needs to be accessible via one of the following share options:

**If the service account is on a different domain to the user that owns the file:**

- **On** - Public on the web
- **On** - Anyone with the link

**If the service account is on the same domain as the user:**

- **On** - Anyone at your organisation can find and access
- **On** - Anyone at your organisation with the link

Alternatively, you can share directly with the service account by selecting `Off - Specific people` and typing the service account's email address in the `People` field in the share dialog from the file itself. The service account's email address can be found in the GCP Project with which it is associated - at console.developers.google.com

#### References:

- [GCP Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- [Google Drive Help - Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&ref_topic=7000947)